# must clean Database after changing acl entries?

Tags: xpages

I have a small problem with an Xpage Application and hope that someone has an
solution:

First some overview:
I have an ACL with 4 User Roles: Admin,User,No Access

In my case I change a Users Role for example from User to Admin.
then open an Xpage witch Uses Java classes I got the following error Message

Error 500
HTTPWeb Server: Could not Handled Exception

to solve this Problem I must "Clean" the project.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this without cleaning? I mean how could a User solve this without a designer?

I would understand how to solve the problem with "clean and build the project"

here is the full error I got after changing the ACL:

```
The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
Error source
Page Name:/ProjectsByName.xsp
Control Id: _id60

Exception
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed   expression
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=27: [ReferenceError] 'de' not found

JavaScript code

1: var exUtils = new de.itwu.RessourceUtils();
2: 
3: return exUtils.computeCountrybox();

► Stack Trace
```

the Stack trace is empty
an the Java-class is in Code/Java with the right package.
after a clean all works fine... nothing else like restarting the HTTP task on a server or restarting the hole server works

Comment: When you update the acl and open the xpage do you login or are you only refreshing the page ?

Comment: I just updated the ACL for one of my XPages projects that also uses beans, and afterwards I got "javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class". I have to clean and re-build too to make it work (and only a clean on the server replica and not my local replica helped)

Comment: 500 is the generic error code returned when anything goes wrong with an XPage, and could mean anything. If you enable the standard error reporting in the application properties, you'll be able to see a full stack trace... this will not only tell you specifically what went wrong, but will typically tell you the exact line of code where it failed.

Comment: If it still just shows a 500 error, check the server Trace logs in <domino install>\data\domino\workspace\logs. The trace logs show more detailed stack traces of where the error occurs and why.

Comment: So I have added the error message... hope someone has an idea that works or better to remove this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your java classes is in the java design element move them to `web-inf\` .

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the HTTP task. NOTE: if doing this via a console command, not via the Administrator GUI, be sure to issue

```
restart task http
```

*not*

```
tell http restart
```

The former completely shuts down the task and starts it again; the latter merely refreshes certain configuration settings.

Doing a full restart of the task causes the JVM to be destroyed, which releases any class instances that may have cached the users' permissions. Cleaning the project forces this to happen on a per-application basis, because the class cached in the JVM no longer exists (as it has been replaced by a newer version), but restarting the HTTP task does the same for all applications without requiring Designer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sessionAsSigner in the database, the database needs to be signed by a consistent signer. If changing the ACL affects the signatures of the database, you could be getting a conflict in the signer. If so, cleaning the project will have no effect.

Try signing the database again. If you're using managed beans, you may need to do a clean to rebuild the class files. I've seen that work in one scenario.

The trace logs may tell you more information. In a standard Domino install they can be found at C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Domino\data\domino\workspace\logs

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the ID you are using the update the database. The change in ACL generates a change in the signer of one of the properties of your db's. The signer does not have the correct privileges. I think that you should check the following url: [An Intro to using xpages](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tutorial/An-introduction-to-using-XPages-in-Domino-85)

> To run an XPage, you must change the server's default security
>   settings. Go to the server's names.nsf -> Configuration -> Servers ->
>   All Server Documents ->  -> Security -> Sign agents or
>   XPages to run on behalf of the invoker. Add the name of the person who
>   last saved the XPage. In our example, that will be you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your cache.ndk from notes client.

If database is in server use

```
dbcache flush
```

for clear you cache memory in server...

If it is not working on both, You should have to restart http or restart your server or Client.